# Changing bucket class(Regional/Multi Regional) in Google Cloud Storage connector in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Currently I am running my Dataproc cluster in region europe.
I am running spark application on same cluster. While writing to bucket using Google cloud storage connector in spark, buckets are automatically getting created with Multi-Regional class and with Multiple Regions in US properties.

I am writing file using

```
dataframe.write("gs://location").mode()...
```

This will create new bucket into location with properties mentioned above.

Tried to find configuration to set storage class in connector but no success. How we can resolve this.

Comment: I don't understand you question. You want to create bucket in Europe but spark create in US? So I want to know how to create in Europe ?

Comment: Yes google cloud storage connector not providing any option to specify storage class and regions.

Comment: You should create the bucket (in Europe Regine) first. Then use that bucket.

Answer (score 2):

From document: [Cloud Dataproc staging bucket](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/staging-bucket)

> When you create a cluster, by default, Cloud Dataproc will create a Cloud Storage staging bucket in your project or reuse an existing Cloud Dataproc-created staging bucket from a previous cluster creation request. This bucket is used to stage cluster job dependencies, job driver output, and cluster config files. Instead of relying on the creation of a default staging bucket, you can specify an existing Cloud Storage bucket that Cloud Dataproc will use as your cluster's staging bucket.

If you create Dataproc cluster by command try to add **--region=REGION**

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name --region region ...
```

Comment: In above query i am not talking about staging bucket. Yes we can control location of staging bucket. But my problem is when i am writing data from dataproc spark job its writing to bucket which storage class as multi regional US location. I want to control that not staging bucket.

Comment: staging bucket is another scenario. But still if you can create bucket for writing first.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage connector does not support bucket location configuration.

Usually this is not an issue because users write into the existing buckets with a storage location that they need.

Comment: Hi Lgor Dvorzhak thanks for your answer. So as of now this api don't have provision for my requirement